# total differentiability of $\frac{x^3z^4}{(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)}$ if the denominator equals $0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^3z^4}{(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)}$ if the denominator is not equal to $0$ and otherwise by $f(x,y,z)=0$.

Find all the points where $f$ is differentiable.

---

$f$ is surely differentiable when the denominator is not equal to zero so we only need to consider the case that $(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)=0$.
However, even if we can show that the partial derivatives of $f$ are not continuous at those points, that still doesn't imply that $f$ is not differentiable there. How do I continue from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $(x,y,z) \neq 0$ and look at $f((tx,ty,tz)) = t^3\frac{x^3z^4}{(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)}$. From this, if $f$ is differentiable, we would expect that
$Df(0) = 0$.

Note that ${x^2 \over x^2+y^2} \le 1$ and ${z^2 \over z^2+y^2} \le 1$ so
$|f((x,y,z))| \le |xz^2|$.

Note that $|xz| \le {1 \over 2} (x^2+z^2)$.

Suppose $|z| \le 2$, then we have $|f((x,y,z))| \le x^2+z^2 \le x^2+y^2+z^2= \|(x,y,z)\|^2$.

Hence $f$ is (Frechet) differentiable at $0$ with derivative $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to copper.hat's answer but worthwhile to point out: If $f(0,0,0)=0$ and $f(x,y,z)=o(|((x,y,z)|)$ as $(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0),$ then $Df(0,0,0)=0.$